What are the typical sizes of Lucas/Differential addition chains used in practice?
I have never looked at Lucas chains until this paper caught my attention:
Bernstein, Daniel J., Jolijn Cottaar, and Tanja Lange. "Searching for differential addition chains." Cryptology ePrint Archive (2024).
I hacked up some existing code I had that calculates addition chains for ranges of numbers. This code doesn't have any sophisticated pruning because it was meant to calculate $\Lambda(n)$ values. $\Lambda(n)$ is the number of shortest addition chains for $n$. Instead of punning it uses parallelism at both the thread level and SIMD level with AVX512.
The shortest Lucas chain for $n$ is denoted $L(n)$. I was able to calculate all $L(n)$ values for $n\le 2^{33}$ and could push it further. I don't have a good way yet to compress the data. For addition chains over these kinds of ranges we can reduce the length data to 2 bits for each $l(n)$ value ($l(n)$ is the length of the shortest addition chain for $n$). I am currently using a whole byte per value for $L(n)$.
The paper above seems to use the range $n\le 10^9$ for testing how efficient their algorithm is (they are not searching for shortest chains) but I am guessing practical exponents are in general very much bigger. Is that the case?

In practice, the most common use of addition/subtraction chains is via the $w$-NAF method which has $\lg n$ doublings and at most $2^w-1+\frac{\lg n}{w+1}$. By taking $w=\lg\lg n-\lg\lg\lg n$ we can see that this is at most $(1+O(1/(\lg\lg n))\lg n$ operations in total. This asymptotically equal to the lower bound of $\lg n$.
For differential addition chains, the most common method is the Montgomery ladder which always uses $2\lg n$ operations. The constant operation count makes it particularly interesting for those concerned with constant tine operations.
Both methods are particularly used for the values $\lg n=256, 384, 520$.

Other than the above, ECM is also a use case for differential addition chains. GMP-ECM uses PRAC, but splits the (enormous) exponent into $p_1^ip_2^j\dots$ to avoid explicitly computing the product.
